# Can't support multiple screen sizes

Tags: android, screen

I have just created a new resource folder in

> \src\main\res\layout\layout-large

that contains the `activity_main-large.xml` with the following code:

```
 <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="LARGE" />
```

But when I run the app on a large screen device it still loads the defalut activity and shows "Hello World!" that I have put in

> \src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml

How should I fix that? I already read about this on the internet but I wrote the code in the correct way so what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have different ressources

1. they need to have the same name, and
2. they need to be in the correct folder

Your other configurations are on the same level, so rename your `large` layout and move it to

> \src\main\res\layout-large\activity_main.xml

This will make it available for large devices.

Comment: update: i coppied the file and change the code inside and now I see that there is red lines in the code, so I right click on the folder > new > xml > create layout.. and it is shows that I can not create layout with same name (the name need must be unique)

Comment: okay sorry my mistake was that I was trying to create folder and put the xml file on res\layout\layout-large instead of res\layout-large , thank you !